# Regular Expression Help for custom tag

Tags: regex

I need to create a regular expression for the following example string

> doc:E529FC2A

where doc: is expected followed by random sequence of 8 characters [A-Z] and [0-9].

Comment: doc:[A-Z0-9]{8} should be fine

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: `/^doc:[A-Z0-9]{8}$/`